# Bootstrap IE background color issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to change the background color of my navbar in IE9. The site uses Twitter-Bootstrap

Here is the website: http://iioengine.com/

The top navbar has a white background in every browser other than IE. It's black in IE. I've tried targeting every part of the element with CSS but nothing has effected its color in IE.

I've also set `background-image` to `none` in all relevant classes

Anyone know what the issue is or what I need to target? IE is driving me crazy.. Thanks

SOLUTION:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner{
  filter:none;
  background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code here, please

Comment: In IE 10 it's working fine? in which version are you testing?

Comment: The external site seems extremely slow or dead

Comment: Really slow.. I've been noticing that too. It's usually very fast, I think GoDaddy is having some issues right now.. I'm using IE9

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is being caused by a MS `filter` gradient on `.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {}`

The solution is to override this with `none` in your own stylesheet:

```
div.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    filter: none;
    background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't find your other answer when I searched, but this is correct. It's much easier to just use 'filter:none' though. I'll accept when lets me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a simlar issue w/IE9 + Bootstrap 3. filter:none did not fix the issue for me. Adding this did:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
```

Answer (score -3):

Filter is the problem as pointed out by @Adrift