# Background-color and border misbehaving in IE version 11

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to make IE 11 behave like Chrome and FF and I'm not sure what to do...

This is the code:

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.2);
    background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.2);
    /*background-color: #484848;*/
    width: 460px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}
```

And this is the effect visually...

[image]

The **background-color** being translucent is being ignored and so is the **border-radius**.  Also, Chrome behaves the same as FF...

Any tip would be appreciated

Dennis

Here is the HTML for that section:

```
<main id="main">
  <div id="resultContainer">
    <section id="i0" class="wDay">
        <h2>
            <span class="day" ></span>
            <span class="temp" ></span>
        </h2>
        <img src="">
        <span class="wDescript" style="color:#2050ff;word-break:break-all;"></span> 
        <span class="wind" ></span><br/> 
        <span class="humid" ></span> 
        <span class="other1" ></span> 
        <span class="other2" ></span> 
    </section>
    <section id="i1" class="wDay">
        <h2>
            <span class="day" ></span>
            <span class="temp" </span>
        </h2>
        <img src="">
        <span class="wDescript" style="color:#2050ff;word-break:break-all;"></span> 
        <span class="wind" ></span><br/> 
        <span class="humid" ></span> 
        <span class="other1" ></span> 
        <span class="other2" ></span> 
    </section>
    <section id="i2" class="wDay">
        <h2>
            <span class="day" ></span>
            <span class="temp" </span>
        </h2>
        <img src="">
        <span class="wDescript" style="color:#2050ff;word-break:break-all;"></span> 
        <span class="wind" ></span><br/>  
        <span class="humid" ></span> 
        <span class="other1" ></span> 
        <span class="other2" ></span> 
    </section>
    <section id="i3" class="wDay">
        <h2>
            <span class="day" ></span>
            <span class="temp" </span>
        </h2>
        <img src="">
        <span class="wDescript" style="color:#2050ff;word-break:break-all;"></span> 
        <span class="wind" ></span><br/>  
        <span class="humid" ></span> 
        <span class="other1" ></span> 
        <span class="other2" ></span> 
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Clearly there is something else going on in IE. We'd need a link.

Comment: @Paulie_D  Unfortunately, I have not published it yet... on the web...

Comment: Don't feel bad. Everybody struggles to make IE behave.

Comment: Could be anything then, a `doctype` issue or a setting in **your** IE.

Comment: Works ok for me in IE11; http://jsfiddle.net/vkfrq1nu/ as said, something else is wrong.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the CSS...it should render fine in IE11 which makes me think this is a local issue.

Comment: Here is the DOCTYPE   <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: This is very odd because CanIUse says that IE11 supports rgba. The border should be a no-duh for IE. http://caniuse.com/css3-colors

Could the file be cached? Sometimes my local files get cached in Chrome and I have to do a hard reload or clear the cache.

Comment: [Is there a css filter being applied?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911272/bootstrap-ie-background-color-issue) Try adding `filter:none;`

Comment: I added the HTML of the of the MAIN section

Comment: @Blazemonger  No filter...

Comment: are you sure you are using latest IE standard, to check press F12 in the bottom right you'll find a dropdown with browser settings in it make sure it is default.

Comment: I figured it out.  the tag <main> is not allowed in IE...  What a trip!

Comment: I tried it with <div> and <section> and it works fine...  MS needs to catch up!

Answer (score 1):

Pull up developer tools and make sure the browser is in standards mode. If you are in compatibility mode, you wouldn't see those styles in IE.

Try adding the X-UA-Compatible meta tag to force standards mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

Comment: Very interesting.  I found the problem to be the <main> tag, but your tip is interesting enough for me to appreciate the reply...  Thanks @Travis

Answer (score 0):

Today is August 8, 2014 and Microsoft does not support the **`<main>`** tag.  div, section, article  etc work just fine...

So, thank you all for the effort to help.

Regards,

Dennis